# Функция length() неправильно работает

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

[image: Код]

[image: Вывод]

Почему функция `length()` определяет длину строки правильно,только 1 раз?

Comment: Сделайте правку, что-бы код был текстом.

Comment: Вообще-то тут принято давать код текстом, а не картинкой... Но - вы определяете `mas` как *массив указателей на `string`*, а в функцию передаете *массив строк*. Странно, что оно у вас скомпилировалось - но не набирать же ваш код с нуля, чтоб посмотреть...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде функция `max5` требует на вход массив строк. Вы в нее передаете указатель на отдельностящую строку `a` и делаете вид, что это начало массива строк. Указатель на строку `a` не является началом никакого массива. Это просто указатель на самостоятельную строку `a`. Любые попытки доступа к элементам такого массива `arr` внутри `max5` (кроме `arr[0]`) попадают "в никуда". Потому вы и получаете чушь из `arr[1]` и `arr[2]`.

Определитесь, что же должна получать ваша функция `max5` - *массив строк* или *массив указателей на строки* и далее действуйте соответствующим образом. Сейчас она требует массив строк. Вот и заводите и передавайте массив строк. К чему вы заводили этот массив указателей `mas` в функции `main` - не ясно.

Comment: Я должен передать данной функции массив из адресов строк. Сейчас попробую исправить.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Код]

Спасибо за помощь,вод измененный код,который выводит все правильно.
Я используют Visual Studia 2019.Довольно странно,что он скомпилировался без ошибки.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>


int max5(string* arr[],int);

int main()
{
    string a, b, c;
    getline(cin,a);
    getline(cin, b);
    getline(cin, c);
    string *mas[3] = { &a,&b,&c };
    int kk=max5(mas, 3);
    cout << kk;
    return 0;
}


int max5(string *arr[],int lol) {
    int z = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lol; i++) {

        if (z<arr[i]->length()) z=arr[i]->length();
        cout << "arr" << i << "=" << arr[i]->length() << endl;
    }
    return z;
}
```

Comment: Но в исходном варианте у вас и не было никаких "ошибок", которые могла бы обнаружить Visual Studio.